# Can I enable a PDF for digital signatures outside Acrobat Pro?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I'm working on a small program to take a large PDF, split it up (using iText), and add digital signature fields to each file. The splitting part works fine, but users with Adobe Reader can't sign the generated files until someone with Acrobat Professional opens them and enables them for Reader.

Is there a way to do the enabling automatically? A Java/iText solution would be my first choice, but anything automated will beat the current system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing PDFs is explained in the [iText in Action](http://www.manning.com/lowagie/) book, including [some examples](http://itext.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itext/book/src/part3/chapter12/).

However it seems that enabling "Usage Rights" cannot be done because it requires a private key owned by Adobe - see [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/Handling-Reader-extensions.-td21764670.html) in the iText mailing list.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but those look like examples of *signing* the PDF -- not *enabling it to be signed in Reader*.

Comment: Uhm it was me that missed something sorry. I'm not clear what this "enabled for signing" feature is. Do you know how it's called in PDF specs?

Comment: That's called "Usage Rights" apparently and it's Adobe-specific. Answer updated.

Comment: Pity. Looks like it's AutoIt for me then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not need anymore reader extensions for digital signature with Acrobat Reader DC. 
See this simular question : [Reader extensions not needed anymore for digital signature in Acrobat Reader DC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634083/reader-extensions-not-needed-anymore-for-digital-signature-in-acrobat-reader-dc)